# How to change relative paths in Franklin.jl?

Tags: html, julia, github-pages

I am trying to host a website in github pages but relative links doesn't work (css is not loaded).

My web page has a base url as follows: `user.github.io/website`
I have the following generated structure in `gh-pages` branch:

```
.  
├── css  
│    └── styles.css  
├── index.html
```

The `index.html` file has the following:

```html
<!doctype html>
   <html lang=en >
   <meta charset=UTF-8 >
   <link rel=stylesheet href="/css/styles.css">
   ...
```

As you can see the link to the style-sheet is `/css/styles.css`, so it would go to my parent directory, resulting in the absolute link: `user.github.io/css/styles.css`, while the correct path should be `user.github.io/`**`website`**`/css/styles.css`.

The only way to fix this at the best of my knowledge is to eliminate the `/` in the href in the index file:

```html
   <link rel=stylesheet href="css/styles.css">
```

But as I have a lot of links and this is an auto generated html I don't know how to fix this from Franklin.jl, also this could be a error of gh pages configuration too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://franklinjl.org/workflow/#publish),

> In any case, before deploying, if you're working on a project website i.e. a website whose root URL will look like username.gitlab.io/project/ then you should add the following line in your config.md file:
>
> ```
> @def prepath = "project"
> ```
>
> the publish function will then ensure that all links are fixed before deploying your website.

In other words, it sounds like you're doing a project website, so you need to let Franklin know by setting `prepath`